# How to load QSqlQuery results to pandas DataFrame effectively?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, qt, pyside2

There is a built-in Pandas method to load data from SQL table and it works with sqlite:

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
cnx = sqlite3.connect('/home/db.sqlite')
%timeit df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table", cnx)
```

It gives `217 ms ± 6.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` for my sample table.

But I have Qt GUI application and work with `QSqlDatabase`,`QSqlQuery`classes. So I use following code:

```py
from PySide2.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName('/home/db.sqlite')
db.open()

def load_pandas(db, statement):    
    query = QSqlQuery(db)
    query.prepare(statement)
    query.exec_()
    table = []
    while query.next():
        values = []
        for i in range(query.record().count()):
            values.append(query.value(i))
        table.append(values)
    return pd.DataFrame(table)

%timeit df = load_pandas(db, "SELECT * FROM table")
```

It results in `429 ms ± 3.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`, i.e. it is twice slower than pandas native routine.

Replacing `query.record().count()` by a constant value I was able to reduce it to `328 ms ± 4.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. But it is still 50% slower...

Is there still any room for more optimization?

Comment: Why are you using QSqlQuery? It's obviously going to be slower because *every single value* must be marshalled between qt and python before passing it to pandas. If you're not using the built-in models, there's no point in using the qt sql classes if performance is a concern. But are you sure this isn't a case of premature optimisation? Your test case doesn't really prove anything. What you need to show is a *very noticeable lag* when interacting with a gui that uses the qt sql claases. If the user can't see any difference, then the timeit numbers are just an irrelevant distraction.

Comment: PS: some small improvements - `query.setForwardOnly(True)` and `indexes = range(query.record().count()); while query.next(): table.append(list(map(query.value, indexes)))`.

Comment: Thanks, you point of view is clear. and thanks for proposal